# ROS viso2 visual odometry package outcome inaccurate

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, viso2, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS viso2 visual odometry package outcome inaccurate
Hi
I`m feeding ROS visual odometry package with pre recorded data. Data is 500 pair of synced 1024*768 bumblebee2 output image( also tested other setting as well). I`ve using opencv to get u,v and focus length. baseline is provided. they are all correct setting

However the output of the RT matrix was quite inaccurate.
during the rotation period, track is lost entirely.

what else I could do to improve the result. Or what should I do?

By the way, the test image sample provide by libviso2 was great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44604/ros-viso2-visual-odometry-package-outcome-inaccurate/) by [snakehaihai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3261/snakehaihai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snakehaihai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3261/snakehaihai/) on 2012-09-26**:
@dejanpan Reply to dejanpan I tried to contact him. But Andreas give a lot of language I don`t understand

**Comment by [snakehaihai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3261/snakehaihai/) on 2012-09-26**:
@ThomasK I`m also using camera a bit tilted down, outdoor in the school scene.  Ok I understand what you said. I`ll set different value and give it a try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

libviso2 works perfectly fine, you just need to tune the parameters to your dataset (e.g. increase the max number of features per bucket for indoor scenes to get more features).

The problem in the other question is caused by a difference in tilt rotation between the camera used to record the dataset (the KIT camera is slightly facing downwards as far as I remember) and the one used to reproduce the results.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0